# How to deploy A contract created by another contract in the browser?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, contract-deployment, javascript, truffle-deployment

Hey I am making a smart contract that create another smart contracts. Organization.sol create Session.sol . When I create a session using createdSession function I got it's address and I already had the abi. Now I need to deploy the contract from the browser(to use function like take_feedback or seeResult). Could anyone tell me how please. 
I run my contract in localhost using `truffle develop` command and MetaMask.

**Solidity code**

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;
//Session

contract Session {

      address public creator;  // The address of parent Organization

      string sessionName;
      string description;
      uint startTime;
      uint endTime;
      address[] lecturer;
      address[] attendes; 

      int[] result; 
      mapping(address => int) public attendes_feedback; //institution boardMembers
      modifier onTime(uint _startTime){
            require(now < _startTime);
            _;
      }
      constructor (string memory _sessionName, string memory _description, uint _startTime,uint _endTime,address[] memory   _lecturer,address[] memory  _attendes) public onTime(_startTime){

              sessionName =  _sessionName;
              description = _description;
              startTime = _startTime;
              endTime = _endTime;
              attendes = _attendes;
              lecturer = _lecturer;
              initAttendes(attendes);
      } 

    function initAttendes(address[] memory _attendes) private{
           for(uint i=0 ; i < _attendes.length ; i++){
            attendes_feedback[_attendes[i]] = -1;
        }
    }

    function Time() public view returns (bool){
       return (now >=  startTime  && now <= endTime);          
     }

    modifier checkTime(){
        require(Time());
        _;
      }
    function take_feedback(address _voter,uint8 _feedback)  public checkTime {
          require(attendes_feedback[_voter] != 0);
          attendes_feedback[_voter] = _feedback;
          result[_feedback]++;
    }

  function seeResult() public view returns(int[] memory){
          return result;
  }

 }

contract Organization {

     address creator;
     event sessionnCreated(string name,address sessionAddress ,address creator);

     /*  modifier onlyCreator(){
        require(msg.sender == creator);
        _;
    } */
     function createdSession(
      string memory _sessionName,
      string memory _description,
      uint _startTime,
      uint _endTime,
      address[] memory _lecturer,
      address[] memory _attendes
     ) public   returns(address) {

        Session sessionAddress = new Session(_sessionName , _description , _startTime , _endTime, _lecturer,_attendes );
        emit sessionnCreated(_sessionName,address(sessionAddress),creator);
        return address(sessionAddress);
     }
}
```

**Web3js Code**

```
    initSession: async function(_address) {
            var abi = web3.eth.contract(SessionArtifact.abi);
            var session = abi.at(_address);
            alert("your session is created!!") 
             /*Deploy Contract here!*/   
               //need to deploy contract first before calling functions
            /*Call  function */
            await session.take_feedback('0xa8ff46045fa2c6a0af361819b62126e1b0ec8909', 5).send({ from: this.account });

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the address of the contract it is most likely already deployed.

You want to access the deployed contract I guess. For that you can just create a new contract with web3 and pass the address as the second parameter.

```javascript
var sessionAddress = await organizationContract.createdSession(...);
var sessionContract = web3.eth.contract(SessionArtifact.abi, sessionAddress);
var creator = await sessionContract.methods.creator().call();
```

Comment: I edited my answer, try again please.

Comment: Unfortunately, It keep telling me "' creator method undefined  '''

Comment: ````var sessionAddress;
        const { createdSession } = this.meta.methods;
        await createdSession(_sessionName, _description, _startTime, _endTime, _lecturer, _attendes).send({ from: this.account });
        sessionAddress = await createdSession(_sessionName, _description, _startTime, _endTime, _lecturer, _attendes).call();
        var sessionContract = web3.eth.contract(SessionArtifact.abi, sessionAddress);
        var creator = await sessionContract.methods.creator.call();
        console.log(creator);````

Comment: I am sorry for how the code look like. I tried to make it more readable. use this link  https://pastebin.com/xsqGp65Y

Comment: Try ```var creator = await sessionContract.methods.creator().call();```

Comment: yeah I already try it. It will give the same result

Comment: I tried to print sessionContract (console.log) and it give me this output https://pastebin.com/tS2zJRNk  just like the normal contract I don't know why I can't access it